# Trying to add geocomplete to a Vue js webpack project

Tags: jquery, webpack, vue.js, geocomplete

I've added Geocomplete to a Vue project before but not with Webpack.  I tried using the [npm module](https://www.npmjs.com/package/geocomplete), which requires the following in index.html:

```
<script src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY&libraries=places"></script>
<script src="jquery.geocomplete.js"></script>
```

(of course, I filled in my api key and it's valid)

When  I try to add geocomplete to an input in my App.vue file:

```
   $("address-input").geocomplete();
```

I get the message:

```
TypeError: __WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_5_jquery___default(...)(...).geocomplete is not a function
```

Any ideas how to use this module with Vue?

Here's my index.html file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <head>

        <script src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?libraries=places&key=mykey"></script>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script> 

      <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/geocomplete/1.7.0/jquery.geocomplete.js"></script>

    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>gotta-go</title>
    <style ></style>


  </head>

  <body>
    <div id="app"></div>
    <!-- built files will be auto injected -->
  </body>
</html>
```

webpack.dev.conf.js:

```
'use strict'
const utils = require('./utils')
const webpack = require('webpack')
const config = require('../config')
const merge = require('webpack-merge')
const baseWebpackConfig = require('./webpack.base.conf')
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin')
const FriendlyErrorsPlugin = require('friendly-errors-webpack-plugin')

// add hot-reload related code to entry chunks
Object.keys(baseWebpackConfig.entry).forEach(function (name) {
  baseWebpackConfig.entry[name] = ['./build/dev-client'].concat(baseWebpackConfig.entry[name])
})

module.exports = merge(baseWebpackConfig, {
  module: {
    rules: utils.styleLoaders({ sourceMap: config.dev.cssSourceMap })
  },
  // cheap-module-eval-source-map is faster for development
  devtool: '#cheap-module-eval-source-map',
  plugins: [
    new webpack.DefinePlugin({
      'process.env': config.dev.env
    }),
    // https://github.com/glenjamin/webpack-hot-middleware#installation--usage
    new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin(),
    new webpack.NoEmitOnErrorsPlugin(),
    // https://github.com/ampedandwired/html-webpack-plugin
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      filename: 'index.html',
      template: 'index.html',
      inject: true
    }),
    new FriendlyErrorsPlugin()
  ]
})
```

Here is my app.vue

```
<template>
  <div>
                    <el-form ref="form" :model="form" label-width="120px">
                        <el-form-item label="Location">                            
                            <el-input id="address-input"></el-input>
                        </el-form-item>                        
                        <el-form-item label="Distance">
                            <el-slider v-model="form.distance"></el-slider>
                        </el-form-item>
                        <el-form-item label="Rating">
                            <el-rate void-color="rgb(100, 100, 100)" v-model="form.rating"></el-rate>
                        </el-form-item>


                        <el-form-item label="special:">                        
                            <el-checkbox-group v-model="form.specials">

                            </el-checkbox-group>                        
                        </el-form-item>                    
                    </el-form>

  </div>

</template>
<script>

 import app from './db.js'


 import Icon from 'vue-awesome/components/Icon'
 import L from 'leaflet'
 import Vue2Leaflet from 'vue2-leaflet'

 var db = app.database()
 var storage = app.storage()
 var usersRef = db.ref('users')
 var toiletsRef = db.ref('toilets')
 var auth = app.auth()



 export default {
     name: 'app',
     components: {         
         Icon,
         'v-map': Vue2Leaflet.Map,
         'v-tilelayer': Vue2Leaflet.TileLayer,
         'v-marker': Vue2Leaflet.Marker         

     },
     mounted(){

         $("#address-input").geocomplete();

     },
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Did you include jquery in your project?

Comment: @EricGuan  Yes.  Before I included it, it complained about $ not being defined, so I know it's included

Comment: Did you include jQuery and Geocomplete directly in index.html file as script tags? or just `require`d from the main app js file so webpack bundles them all together?

Comment: @karamarimo   I included them directly in the index.html file.  I'll post my code...

Comment: but according to the error message, webpack knows jQuery as a dependency, right?

Comment: @karamarimo   Yes, as far as I know

Comment: I think that doesn't happen when you just include jQuery as a script tag. Maybe you are `require`ing jQuery from the vue app or adding jQuery alias in webpack config. Could you post your webpack config?

Comment: That's not the webpack config. I guess you used vue-cli to create the project. Actually there are 3 webpack config files under `build/` folder. Did you edit them? If you didn't, you don't need to post them here.

Comment: @karamarimo

Yeah I used vue-cli.  Which of the three files do you need?  I'll post dev.conf.js

Comment: The ones you edited.

Comment: @karamarimo   I didn't edit any webpack config

Comment: Then could you post your vue file that is using geocomplete?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried to replicate the problem, but geocomplete worked fine.

All i did was:

1. Create project using vue-cli. `vue init webpack my-project` and `npm i`.
2. Enable Google Map APIs.
3. Edit `index.html` and `App.vue` as below.

**index.html**

```
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>vue-webpack-playground</title>
    <script src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?libraries=places&key=MYAPIKEY"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script> 
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/geocomplete/1.7.0/jquery.geocomplete.js"></script>
  </head>
```

**App.vue**

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <input type="text">
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: 'app',
  mounted: function () {
    $("input").geocomplete();
  }
}
</script>
```

**Result**

[image]

Comment: did you use npm to install geocomplete?

Comment: @DavidJ. no, i didn't add any packages.

Comment: I added my App.vue to the question.  I'm going to try to follow your example and see if I run into any problems.  Thanks for the help!

Comment: I retried this from scratch with your instructions and it worked, thanks again.

Comment: @DavidJ. no problem.